# Get selected datepicker weekday in occurence in month

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to make a replica of the Google Calender repetition dialog, and I'm stuck, when I trying to figure out how to get jQuery datepicker to return the number of weekdays in a month, for example if I select a date and it's a Wednesday, I would like datepicker to tell me the number of Wednesdays in that month I've selected, for December 2012, if I select the 26. December it should return 4 or fourth.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datePick").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(event,ui){
        $(ui.dpDiv)
           .children(".ui-datepicker-calendar")
           .find("td")
           .filter(function() {
               if($(this).text() === ui.selectedDay){
                   var col = $(this).parents("tr")
                                     .children("td")
                                     .index($(this));
                    var row = $(this).parents("tbody")
                                     .children("tr")
                                     .index($(this).parents("tr"));

          if($(this).parents("tbody").children("tr").eq(0).children("td").eq(col).hasClass("ui-datepicker-unselectable")){
                 $("#result").text(row);   
              }else{
                 $("#result").text(row + 1);
                   }
               }

})
           }
    });
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/93RGW/108/

Hope this helps and let me know if you need anything else!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "DD, MM d, yy"
});
```